# What can I use freely in HTML5 and CSS3? What features should I avoid?

Tags: html, css

What features can I use in HTML5 and CSS3 without thinking too much about IE6 and similar? What features should I avoid?

Comment: IE6 dates back to 2001, long before HTML5 was even proposed. e.g. You can use absolutely NOTHING in html5/css3 that didn't exist in '01 when on IE6.

Comment: Perhaps clarify what you mean by 'without thinking too much' !

Comment: I don't have a comprehensive list, but the new input types will fall back gracefully.  Any input type unrecognized just becomes a text box.

Comment: @marc B - a lot of css3 features would just progressively enhance for non ie6 users, but some html5 features might break - like using header or footer without a shim.

Comment: @MarcB: Well, it's like an example I guess.

Comment: If you think about IE6 _at all_, you're better off with `<table>`s for layout and `<font>` in place of CSS ;-P

Comment: Definitely consider using [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to identify the features that are available and fall back gracefully.

Comment: JavaScript can emulate in IE6 a lot of basic HTML5 features, called "polyfills".

Comment: @Marc B: `@font-face` was in the CSS1 drafts as early as the late 90s and managed to carry over to CSS3 (see [this 1997 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-font-970721#AtRule)). But that's in IE6 with a proprietary format and I should just show myself out now... :)

Comment: Avoid being generic in supported browser specs. My list of things to avoid will ***greatly*** differ if IE6 or IE7 are on the list. May as well start thinking "Ohh, what if grandma wants to visit the site - gotta support Netscape 4"

Comment: @MichaelHaren I jest, I jest!

Answer (score 4):

> What features can I use in HTML5 and CSS3 without thinking too much about IE6 and similar?

Define "too much". Anything that is in HTML 4 and CSS 1 makes for a very safe baseline…

On a more practical note [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) will tell you when support for a particular feature has been added. You then need to decide if it will degrade cleanly or not.

That said, don't go looking HTML 5 / CSS 3 / etc features to use. If you have a problem, look for a solution. Don't look for a solution and then try a find a problem to solve with it.

Comment: Your last sentence pretty much sums up my disdain for the self-proclaimed "HTML5/CSS3 web developers".

Answer (score 2):

http://www.caniuse.com/ is a great resource when you have a particular feature in mind to use - but are but sure the of browser compatibility.

In addition, many HTML5/CSS3 features have additional links with further information available on Can I Use.

Answer (score 1):

[Paul Irish](http://paulirish.com/) has an awesome commented [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

From "Why it is awesome":

> Cross-browser compatible (IE6, yeah we got that.) HTML5 ready. Use the
>   new tags with certainty.

Answer (score 1):

Open this website in IE6 and find out: http://html5test.com/

(I don't have IE6 installed so I can not check it for you atm)

You also might wanna have a look at: [HTML5 Cross Browser Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to avoid many things :-)

I would start by avoiding: 
- Drag and Drop API, 
- File API

Answer (score 0):

[Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/compatibility.html) has always done me well. 
I think you should be a little more specific in your question - I don't worry about IE compatibility so I would say use them All. However I know that view is not shared by all, So i think a better answer would be *use them all until you run into one that explicitly is not compatible with your target browsers / os*

Once you start to see problems then work on correcting them.

I will say it once again - put together a specific list of supported browsers / os and you will be much much better off (hint - don't support < IE9 if you want to use the majority of these features)

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 doctype (`<!doctype html>`) works just fine in IE 6 (in as much as it puts IE 6 into [standards mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html)).

Aside from that, I think pretty much nothing new in HTML5 or CSS3 (apart from `@font-face`) is supported in IE 6, so you’ll have to at least decide whether the experience in IE 6 is good enough. Usefully though, the new features generally don’t have any negative effect in IE 6.

For example, the new `<input>` types like `<input type="date">` will render just like `<input type="text">` in IE 6. So you’ll have to decide whether just having a simple text input is fine for IE 6 users, or whether you need to provide date-picking functionality using JavaScript.

This is pretty much the question with all HTML5/CSS3 features — can users of older browsers do without them, or do you need to add an alternative implementation?

The main exception is new tags in HTML5 — [Internet Explorer 6 won’t let you style tags that it doesn’t know about, unless you create an instance of that tag using JavaScript](http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/). (The same is true of the HTML 4 tag `<abbr>`, because IE for some reason doesn’t know about that either.)